# GET Parameters cannot be retrieved from the Laravel Controller, after making it live to Linux Server

Tags: laravel, get, request

I am having an issue after making my Laravel Project live on the Server. Any GET parameters cannot be retrieved from the controller in the entire project, whereas it is running fine on my local server and I also tried in different servers, but when I switching it to the Production Server it is not been able to read the URL Parameters.

For Example, If I consider the URL as below:
http://www.example.com/?type=moble&value=recharge

My Controller Function

```
    /***** In the Starting I had declared use Illuminate\Http\Request; *****/


    public function index(Request $request)
    {
          echo $request->type;
          echo $request->value; 
    }
```

Suppose the above URL pointed to this **index** function, it is returning NULL in the server.

Comment: What server it is? Check nginx configuration for app

Comment: Please post your route

Comment: It's a Linux Server of Hotgator

Comment: This is my Route Lokks like fot this Function:

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the issues out. It was a problem in the **htaccess** file.

Answer (score 0):

First we should check  in php.ini (variables_order = "GPCS").variables_order should be open and the check your .htaccess file.It should be RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).